# Is a releasable locator beacon (ELT) required for aircraft carrying passengers over a water area?

Tags: regulations, search-and-rescue

Is an [Emergency locator transmitter - ELT](https://www.acrartex.com/products/catalog/elts-general-aviation/me406-ace-elt/) required on any type of aircraft carrying passengers over water? Does it need to be fitted with an [hydrostatic release unit](http://www.cmhammar.com/products/onboard/h20/epirbs/) so that it doesn't sink with the aircraft?

If they don't carry a releasable ELT, how are aircraft planned to be located after an accident over the ocean?

References to regulatory documentation definitely a plus (e.g. for the US, or for island countries like Australia or New Zealand).

Comment: related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/do-flight-recorders-float-in-water

Comment: [14 CFR 91.207 for FAA](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.207), ELTs are required to be carried, but they do not have to be hydrostatically released since this would require external mounting. ELTs have to operate for 48 hours. In the event of a water "landing", many FDR's have a sonar "ping" for location purposes, but I don't think the ELT is required to operate under water.

Comment: I know you are asking about *requirements*, but Honeywell does make a [water activated ELT](http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/portal/Common/Documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/BA_brochures-documents/ELT_For_Web.pdf) which looks to be a "portable" unit. It is TSO'd but it doesn't look like something you mount, just carry on board. It doesn't say anything about hydrostatic release. All the other ELT's are G-Force activated.

Comment: @mins I know, I was just mentioning that FDR's have the ability to operate under water, while I don't believe that there is a requirement for ELT's to operate under water, since the radio waves don't work very well under water. Its also important to note that Helicopters are not required to carry ELT's for Part 135 operations, even carrying passengers... Read 14 CFR 91.207 closely, it says air**plane**, not air**craft**...

Comment: @RonBeyer: Agreeing with your last comment. Does 14 CFR 91.207.f.2 "*Aircraft while engaged in scheduled flights by scheduled air carriers*" prevent the requirement to apply to airlines?

Comment: @mins Yes, that is how I would read that, although it does not prevent an airline from carrying it, it does not require them to. Oddly enough it would require them to be carrying one during a ferry flight since section (e) would not apply, if it were a repositioning flight that is.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yes this is strange, as an aircraft used for a charter flight (not a scheduled flight) would need to have an ELT.

Comment: @mins I guess it depends, looking at it again, f.11 could apply to remove the requirement: *On and after January 1, 2004, aircraft with a maximum payload capacity of more than 18,000 pounds when used in air transportation.*

Comment: @RonBeyer: [More confusing](http://www.ntsb.gov/safety/safety-recs/recletters/A-10-169-170.pdf): "*An ELT is required on all U.S.-registered civil airplanes, per 14 Code of Federal Regulations 91.207*", and BTW, how serious is mounting an ELT this way :(

Comment: So why would they specify in paragraph (a) that it applies to part 121 then turn around and specifically exempt them in paragraph (f)? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is an ELT required on any type of aircraft carrying passengers over water?**

Generally, commercial transport aircraft are not required to carry an ELT.

> **how are aircraft planned to be located after an accident over the ocean?**

1. I believe pilots are expected to use radio to inform controllers of any emergency.
2. If ATC are unable to contact an aircraft for an extended time, they instigate S&R based on the last known location of the aircraft.
3. The FDR and CVR are required to include an underwater location beacon (ULB), though this is only short range and has limited duration.
4. It is expected that, sometime in the future, commercial transport aircraft will be required to have automated systems that report their position frequently (perhaps every 15 minutes)

---

References:

- [IATA - Aircraft Tracking Task Force (ATTF)](http://www.iata.org/pressroom/pr/pages/2014-06-03-1.aspx)
- [ATTF FAQ](http://www.iata.org/pressroom/Documents/aircraft-tracking-task-force-faqs.pdf)
- [ICAO Normal Aircraft Tracking Implementation Initiative](http://www.icao.int/safety/globaltracking/Documents/NATII%20Final%20Report.pdf)